# Query regarding consumers in Spring JmsListener annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I've a query regarding Spring JmsListener annotation. I was reading through the spring documentation and understood that Spring JMSListener receives messages asynchronously. Suppose there are 3 concurrent consumers registered for my listener and let's assume that the queue on which my listener is registered has 3 message at the same time.
Is it correct to say that all these three messages will be processed concurrently by 3 separate threads at the same time. In other words:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {
@Autowired
private SomeService someService;

  @JmsListener(destination = "someQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
    someService.process(message)
  }
}
```

Will the `someService.process(message)` be called concurrently by 3 separate threads or will this be a blocking execution?